# Cyclic Group Presentation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-presentation

Show that the the group with presentation $$\langle x, y\ \mid\ x^2=y^2x^2y,\ (xy^2)^2=yx^2, \ yx^{-1}y^2=x^7\rangle $$ is cyclic of order 24.

This presentation was obtained using the Todd-Coxeter process for a subgroup of index 2 in the group presented in problem 476854.

Comment: Hint: try drawing the Cayley graph with $x,y$ as generators.

Comment: I think it might be easier to let $z=x*y^{-1}$ and eliminate $x$.

Comment: Have you tried to prove that x any y commute? If you look at the abelianisation of your group, you can see easily that this is enough.

Comment: @user1729 yes I also looked at the abelianisation.

Comment: @user1729: I've used 7 papers to find out $xy=yx$ but I couldn't prove that. Yes It is enough for this group.

Comment: @B.S. Thought I might as well state the obvious :-)

Comment: 1 and 3 give $[x,y]=x^8$, and in the abelianisation, $x$ has order 8. So...can we prove that x has order 8 here?

Comment: ^How do you get that exactly? 
2 and 3 seems to give that $[x, y]=x^8y^{-3}$, so if you're also right, then we know $y$ has order $3$, and then 1 immediately gives that $x$ and $y$ commute.

Comment: @Nishant I am doing this in my head, but I am pretty sure I am right. I was defining $[x, y]=yxy^{-1}x^{-1}$, and I just replaced $y^2$ in 3.

Comment: Oh darn, my $[x, y]$ is equal to $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$.

Comment: But our two versions are inverses, which means $x^{-8}=x^{8}y^{-3}$.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I should have written $[y, x]$. Your confusion is my fault!

Comment: @naslundx: Can you explain why this question is closed please?

Comment: @Hayden: Can you explain why this question is closed again  please? !

Comment: @mesel If the question was interesting enough to attract the efforts of several people, it seems a likely candidate to remain open.

Comment: @James: I think so and I do not see any reason to close this question.

Comment: @mesel, etc: You should vote to reopen if you disagree with the closure.

Comment: @Derek The question had been closed twice now!

Comment: @DerekHolt: after it is reopened, it is again 
closed. Now, I can not revote again.

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik What are the generators you are using (in terms of $a$,$b$)? I'd like to see if I get the same presentation.

Comment: @mesel, etc. I don't think I am allowed to vote to reopen; or I don't know how to. The OP has now added some context, however.  Perhaps that will help.

Comment: @James $x=a, y=b^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2=y^2x^2y$$

$$x=x^{-1}y^2x^2y=y^{-1}(yx^{-1}y^2)x^2y$$
$$x=y^{-1}x^9y$$

then we can say that;

$$y^2x^2y=x^2=y^{-1}x^{18}y$$
$$y^2x^2=y^{-1}x^{18}$$
$$y^3=x^{16}$$

Now, $$(xy^2)^2=yx^2$$
$$xy^2xy^2=yx^2$$
$$xy^2x(y^3)=yx^2y=y^3x^2y^2=x^{18}y^2$$
$$y^2x^{17}=x^{17}y^2$$
$$y^5x=xy^{5}$$

As a last step;

$$x^2=y^2x^2y$$
$$x^{18}=x^2y^3=y^3x^2=(y^5x^2)y=x^2y^6$$
$$x^2y^3=x^2y^6$$
$$e=y^3$$

Thus, we can say that $x,y^2$ will commute with each other so will $x,y^4=y$. And $x=y^{-1}x^9y=x^9\implies x^8=e$. From that point you can easily conclude that $G$ is an cyclic group of order $24$.

---

**N.Q.E.D**

Comment: In the antepenultimate equality, I think you mean $x^{18}$ instead of $x^{14}$?

Also, how to you get that $x$ and $y^2$ commute? The 1st identity says that $y$ and $x^2$ commute...

Comment: "N.Q.E.D."?${}$

Comment: @Nishant: yeah it is $x^{18}$ before last step we have found that $x,y^5$ commute with each other and in last step we found that $y^3=e$ that is why $y^2,x$ commute each other.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: 'Not quite easily done'

Answer (score 2):

First we manipulate the relations to show that the group $G$ defined by the presentation is the direct product $\langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle$, with $x$ of order a divisor of $8$ and $y$ of order a divisor of $3$. Then, to show that $x$ and $y$ have orders $8$ and $3$ exactly, we exhibit a homomorphism from $G$ onto a group in which the images of $x$ and $y$ have those respective orders.

Let's label the relations for easier reference, thus:
$$x^2 = y^2x^2y;\tag{e1}\label{e1}$$
$$yx^{-1}y^2 = x^7;\tag{e2}\label{e2}$$
$$(xy^2)^2 = yx^2.\tag{e3}\label{e3}$$
From \eqref{e2} we get
$$y^2 = xy^{-1}x^7.\tag{e4}\label{e4}$$
Using \eqref{e1} and \eqref{e4} we can derive the following.
$$\begin{align}
    x^2 &\stackrel{\eqref{e1}}= y^2x^2y \\
        &\stackrel{\eqref{e4}}= xy^{-1}x^7x^2y \\
        &= xy^{-1}x^9y,
\end{align}$$
which implies
$$x = y^{-1}x^9y \;\;\text{and}\;\; x^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-9}y.\tag{e5}\label{e5}$$
Using \eqref{e5} in \eqref{e2}, we obtain
$$x^7 \stackrel{\eqref{e2}}= yx^{-1}y^2 \stackrel{\eqref{e5}}= y(y^{-1}x^{-9}y)y^2 = x^{-9}y^3.\tag{e6}\label{e6}$$
From this follows the crucial relation
$$x^{16} = y^3.\tag{e7}\label{e7}$$
In particular, $y^3$ commutes with $x$ (and hence, with its powers).

Next, we use \eqref{e2} and \eqref{e7} as follows:
$$\begin{align}\tag{e8}\label{e8}
x^7y &\stackrel{\eqref{e2}}= yx^{-1}y^3 \\
     &\stackrel{\eqref{e7}}= yx^{-1}x^{16} \\
     &= yx^{15}.
\end{align}$$

Now, because $y^3$ commutes with $x$, we can write
$$x^2y^2 \stackrel{\eqref{e1}}= y^2x^2y^3 = y^5x^2,$$
and then, using that $y^3$ commutes with $x^{-1}$ (and \eqref{e2}), we get
$$x^7y^{-5} \stackrel{\eqref{e2}}= yx^{-1}y^3 = y^{-2}x^{-1} = (xy^2)^{-1}.$$
Taking inverses, this leads to
$$xy^2 = y^5x^{-7}.\tag{e9}\label{e9}$$
But,
$$\begin{align}
yx^2 &\stackrel{\eqref{e3}}= (xy^2)^2 \\
     &\stackrel{\eqref{e9}}= y^5x^{-7}y^5x^{-7} \\
     &\stackrel{\eqref{e2}}= y^5(y^{-2}xy^{-1})y^5(y^{-2}xy^{-1}) \\
     &=y^3xy^2xy^{-1};
\end{align}$$
whence
$$x^2 = y^2xy^2xy^{-1} = (y^2x)^2y^{-1}.\tag{e10}\label{e10}$$
Now,
$$\begin{align}
yx^2 &\stackrel{\eqref{e3}}= (xy^2)^2 \\
     &\stackrel{\eqref{e9}}= y^5x^{-7}y^5x^{-7} \\
     &\stackrel{\eqref{e2}}= y^5(y^{-2}xy^{-1})y^5(y^{-2}xy^{-1}) \\
     &= y^3xy^2xy^{-1},
\end{align}$$
so that
$$x^2 = y^2xy^2xy^{-1} = (y^2x)^2y^{-1}.\tag{e11}\label{e11}$$
Therefore,
$$y^2x^2y \stackrel{\eqref{e1}}= x^2
          \stackrel{\eqref{e11}}= (y^2x)^2y^{-1},$$
which, upon cancelling $y^2x$ on the left leaves us with
$xy = y^2xy^{-1}$
or, equivalently,
$$xy^2 = y^2x.$$

Recall, however, that also $y^3$ commutes with $x$ so, in fact, $y$ itself
commutes with $x$.

We're almost done.  Using the knowledge that $x$ and $y$ commute,
the first relation \eqref{e1} gives us that $x^2 = x^2y^3$, or $y^3=1$.
Then, from $y^3 = 1$ and \eqref{e2} we get
$$x^7 = yx^{-1}y^2 = x^{-1}y^3 = x^{-1},$$
so that $x^8 = 1$.

This shows that the group $G$ defined by your presentation is abelian,
generated by $x$ of order dividing $8$ and $y$ of order dividing $3$.
Since the orders of $x$ and $y$ are coprime, we have
$$\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle = 1$$
in $G$, and so $G = \langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle = \langle xy\rangle$
is cyclic.  We also know that the order of $G$, which is equal to $\mid\langle x\rangle\mid\cdot\mid\langle y\rangle\mid$, is a *divisor* of $24 = 8\cdot 3$.

Finally, to show that the orders of $x$ and $y$ are indeed $8$ and $3$, respectively,
I'll leave it as an exercise to show that the map
$$G\to\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)(9,10,11)\rangle$$
defined on the generators by
$$x\mapsto (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)\;\;\text{and}\;\; y\mapsto (9,10,11)$$
does indeed define a homomorphism.  (Just check that the permutation
images of $x$ and $y$ satisfy the relations.)

Comment: +100k Very good James. As I commented above, I did these tedious manipulations on 7 sheet of papers but couldn't find the right way. Awful relations. (-:

Comment: @B.S.: do you know why this question is closed?

Comment: @mesel: No :-( Not really know the possible reasons. It is a good one at least for me. I vote for reopen. :-)

Comment: @B.S. It only took me two sheets of paper.  (But I used an eraser. :-)

Comment: I would guess that the question was closed because it lacks context. There is no information about where it came from, why it is interesting, etc. I will vote to reopen.